# how does one function not running iteratively or recursively could produce such a result?

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to get some insight with this code. What happens is weird though but I came up with a theory that since the expression before the `&&` operator is evaluated to `true` and it should continue `obj.value` should point to itself. Tell me what you think;

```
function a() {
    var obj = {};
    return obj.value = 1 && obj;
}
a();
a();
```

This return the object `obj` with a property `value` storing `obj` itself repeatedly, but wasn't in anyway inside a recursive or iterative process.

Comment: Where recursion comes. I don't see you calling a function inside another? What is your expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
return obj.value = 1 && obj;
```

is, actually, evaluated as:

```
return obj.value = (1 && obj);
```

The expression `(1 && obj)` is a logical expression, and they are evaluated following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) documentation and using [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), from `MDN`:

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - (some falsy expression) && expr is short-circuit evaluated to the falsy expression;
> - (some truthy expression) || expr is short-circuit evaluated to the truthy expression.
>
> Short circuit means that the expr parts above are not evaluated, hence any side effects of doing so do not take effect (e.g., if expr is a function call, the calling never takes place). This happens because the value of the operator is already determined after the evaluation of the first operand.

In your particular case, first the expression `1` is evaluated and return a `truthy` value, so now the second expression needs to be evaluated to determine the final value of the expression, i.e, the expression `obj` is evaluated, and finally return `obj` as the final value of the logical expression. This final value is then assigned to `obj.value` and `obj.value` is returned. A more transparent way to understand what you are doing is looking at the next similar code:

```js
function a()
{
    var obj = {};
    obj.value = obj;
    return obj.value;
}

console.log(a());
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, I think, you were looking to do this instead:

```js
function a()
{
    var obj = {};
    return (obj.value = 1) && obj;
}

console.log(a());
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought the same way I just wanted to make sure I was right thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Please, take into consideration accept the answer if it helps you.